# Going back and forward between different stacks via "Back" key

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

Here is my code:

```
  const Stack1 = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Aone: AoneScreen,
        Atwo: AtwoScreen,
    }
    const Stack2 = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Bone:BoneScreen,
        Btwo: BtwoScreen,
    }
    const Stack3 = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Cone:ConeScreen,
        Ctwo: CtwoScreen,
    }

    const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    Stack1,
    Stack2,
    Stack3
    )
```

When I'm in a stack like "AoneScreen" and I move into another stack, say "CtwoScreen", and then press "back" button, instead of moving back to the first stack AoneScreen, it moves to the top of the second stack (ConeScreen) As it should! But that's not what I desire.  what I want is go back to the original stack as the back button is pressed  (in this case "AoneScreen" ) and I was wondering if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom behaviour for back button on screen "CtwoScreen" with BackHandler from React Native, it only depends on how dynamic this needs to be. 
[From documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler):

```js
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";

componentDidMount() {
  this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.handleBackPress);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.backHandler.remove()
}

handleBackPress = () => {
// add some kind of custom check if you want this behaviour only sometimes, nav params are a good way
  if (this.props.navigation.state.params.isFromAOneScreen) { 
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ isFromAOneScreen: false });
    this.props.navigation.popToTop(); // to remove COneScreen from stack, from transition
    this.props.navigation.navigate("AOneScreen");
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```